# ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'NSPersistentStoreCoordinator' with no type

Tags: xcode, core-data, objective-c++

I have .mm file that I want under function to work with core data

// in header file

```
/*Saving parameters*/
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;       
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


/* 1. Check if employee exists*/


NSEntityDescription *employeeentity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"employees" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:employeeentity];
NSError *error;
NSArray* employee_info = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


if (employee_info !=nil) {

    NSLog(@"employee Exist");



}
else {

    NSLog(@"employee NOT Exist");

}
```

I use mm because I work with cpp also any suggestion please

Best regards

Comment: u can mix the two objective c and c++ at the same file, u need to read about that

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the statement "I use mm because I work with cpp". I do realize that you can use C++ syntax in Objective-C. I'm still confused though. Your title mentions `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, yet I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: it's in the header file , I posted part of it the header contains definistions NSPersistentStoreCoordinator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a C++ guy at all. But if I'm allowed to make an educated guess:

For me it sounds like the compiler does not know what NSPersistentStoreCoordinator is.
So you should include the header `<CoreData/CoreData.h>` or tell him that this class exists with the C++ equivalent of `@class NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`